# SpringBoot Data JPA Specification does not work for IN CLUASE for version 1.5.10.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, in-clause

Following code work perfectly fine for Spring boot **org.springframework.boot** version **2.0.3.RELEASE**, here I am trying to apply **IN** clause.

**//import**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DeferredImportSelector.Group;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
```

**//code**

```
final Collection<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
...
final Path<Group> group = root.<Group> get("countryId");
predicates.add(group.in(selected_country_ids));
```

However, Group seems to be not working in **org.springframework.boot** version **1.5.10.RELEASE**

Comment: I doubt that the `Group` you are importing is the one you actually want to use. That `Group` class is used by the Spring framework itself to do grouping on configuration classes. It is not for use in JPA.

Comment: it works as per expectation and generates the correct SQL query at the backend `where countryId IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: It shouldn't have, as I doubt that `Group` is a managed JPA type. It shouldn't have worked imho. You are building a query for a non JPA managed entity that should be stopped by JPA/hibernate when parsing the queries. Replace the `Group` with the proper type your own `Group` or `Country`. It all boils down that you are using the wrong type.

Comment: bro it works and i tried this solution by googling it (otherwise i would have no idea how to do it). If you know any way to do it. I would love to adopt that.

Comment: It shouldn’t have worked in the first place. The fact that it works with a newer version of JPA and HIbernate (that is what you het in Spring Boot 2) doesn’t mean it is right. THe code is simply wrong. The `Group` should be YOUR entiteit you want the `countryId` Property from nog just any arbitrary object.